# Check if user submitted daily user using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've setup the following scenario whereby I need to return users who haven't submitted an entry for the current day.

Below is the sample data being used

```
var entries = new List<Entry> {
    new Entry { UserId = "fce465f6-089d-4416-a631-7b8201c759d6", Name = "Bugs Bunny", Email = "bugs@bunny.com", CreatedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) },
    new Entry { UserId = "1b77f86a-4aad-4788-aa0c-791a7b734181", Name = "Daffy Duck", Email = "daffy@duck.com", CreatedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) },
    new Entry { UserId = "b293bc9d-7626-4c66-888b-e45daebf8322", Name = "Yosemite Sam", Email = "yosemite@sam.com", CreatedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) }
    new Entry { UserId = "ff8321fa-b241-456a-b618-826fdd75aaf2", Name = "Pepe Le Pew", Email = "pepe@lepew.com", CreatedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) },

    new Entry { UserId = "fce465f6-089d-4416-a631-7b8201c759d6", Name = "Bugs Bunny", Email = "bugs@bunny.com", CreatedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(0) },
    new Entry { UserId = "1b77f86a-4aad-4788-aa0c-791a7b734181", Name = "Daffy Duck", Email = "daffy@duck.com", CreatedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(0) },
    new Entry { UserId = "b293bc9d-7626-4c66-888b-e45daebf8322", Name = "Yosemite Sam", Email = "yosemite@sam.com", CreatedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(0) }
};
entries.ForEach(e => context.Entries.Add(e));
context.SaveChanges();
```

In this instance, I'm expecting a single record to be returned as there is no entry for **Pepe Le Pew** for the current day.

I'm using the following snippet but I'm struggling to get my head around the **Where** statement.

```
var entries = db.Entries
    .GroupBy(e => e.UserId)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(e => e.CreatedDate)
        .Where(e =>
            DbFunctions.TruncateTime(e.CreatedDate) < currentDay.Date
            && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(e.CreatedDate) != currentDay.Date)
        .FirstOrDefault())
    .ToList();
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Massive credit to @DavidG for the below solution

```
var entries = db.Entries
    .Where(e => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(e.CreatedDate) < currentDay.Date)
    .Select(e => e.UserId)
    .Except(db.Entries.Where(e => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(e.CreatedDate) == currentDay.Date).Select(e => e.UserId))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need start with a list of all unique users, for example:

```
var allUsers = entries
    .GroupBy(u => new { u.UserId })
    .Select(u => new u.Key.UserId);
```

Then you have a query to get all users that have submitted an entry today:

```
var entriesToday = db.Entries
    .Where(e => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(e.CreatedDate) == currentDay.Date)
    .GroupBy(e => e.UserId)
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Now combine them using [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx) by either making one big query:

```
var entries = db.Entries
    .GroupBy(u => new { u.UserId })
    .Select(u => u.Key.UserId)
    .Except(db.Entries
                .Where(e => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(e.CreatedDate) == currentDay.Date)
                .GroupBy(e => e.UserId)
                .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Or because this will use deferred execution, you could simplify it by using the results from the first two queries:

```
var entries = allUsers.Except(entriesToday);
```

Comment: Doh! This returns 4 records as well.

Comment: Do you have a users list too?

Comment: I only have an Entries table so far. If needs I could add a Users table.

Comment: Try this edit, haven't got a db to test with but should work.

Comment: Getting the following error on .Except( 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Except<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments